# Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Complete code :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"]});

client.commands = new Discord.Collection()
client.events = new Discord.Collection()

['command', 'event'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord)
});

client.login('tokenremoved')
```

Comment: what line throws the error ?

Comment: This `['command', 'event'].forEach(handler =>{...})` is not causing you error for sure.

Comment: An error message and some code. What have you done so far to debug this?

Answer (score 2):

This error is actually caused by "automatic semicolon injection". If you don't put semicolons in your code, Javascript will add them under the hood to the best of its ability. It's very accurate, however, there are a few instances such as this one where it misunderstands what's written.

```js
// javascript sees this:
client.events = new Discord.Collection()

['command', 'event'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord)
});

// and translates it to this:
client.events = new Discord.Collection()['command', 'event'].forEach(handler =>{
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord)
});
```

Javascript thinks you're trying to access a parameter off `Discord.Collection()` with the brackets. However, since `Collection#command` doesn't exist, it returns undefined. Thus:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

```js
const test = 'hello'

[true, 123].forEach(() => 'this throws an error')
```

The solution is just to add a semicolon after `Discord.Collection()`

Comment: Well-spotted for sure!